# Spark: Convert/concat an WrappedArray of Row to a String

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe with column that has `array<struct<_1:long,_2:string>>` datatype and following sample data:

```
WrappedArray([Value,Title1], [Value,Title2], [Value,Title3])
```

I want to convert this column from `WrappedArray` to a single `String`

Here is the desired output:

```
Value+Title1,Value+Title2,Value+Title3
```

I tried the following `udf` passing that column of the dataframe:

```
val f = (x:Seq[Row]) => x.mkString(",")
sqlContext.udf.register("f", f)
```

But the result is `[Value,Title1],[Value,Title2],[Value,Title3]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
val f = (x:Seq[Row]) => x.map(row => "%s+%s".format(row.getString(0), 
row.getString(1))).mkString(",")
```